# Translating a curl to python requests

Tags: python, api, curl

I'm trying to create a python script to interact with an API for a system called Xibo. My problem is that I don't know python very well and the documentation for this system is what could generously be described as poor. Parts of their documentation use the format of the requests but their official API manual suggested the following curl command to update a media file on the system. I understand that requests are the best format to interact with APIs over and above curl so obviously I'd rather do it in requests if the general idea is that it's better.

```
curl -X POST "http://129.12.19.62/api/library" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "files=@47.htz" -F "name=47" -F "oldMediaId=47" -F "updateInLayouts=1" -F "deleteOldRevisions=1"
```

That is the command. Could anyone give me assistance by helping me translate it to the format of a request? I have tried using [curl.trillworks](https://curl.trillworks.com/) but for some reason, it says that there was an `"Error parsing curl command."`. I understand if this is not possible or if you need some more information, I'll do my best to provide what anyone needs to help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like this website doesn't like double spaces - which you have after both `-H`. After deleting the additional spaces, it converts the request.

Comment: @finchy911 BTW curl.trillworks is good tool.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. You're absolutely correct. Thank you both very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import requests

entry_point = 'http://129.12.19.62/api/library'

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}

data = {
    'files': '@47.htz',
    'name': '47',
    'oldMediaId': '47',
    'updateInLayouts': '1',
    'deleteOldRevisions': '1'
}

r = requests.post(entry_point, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: Well I can certainly say that this does not throw an error. Due to lack of knowledge on my part I cant say that everything is working now but I think you may have gotten me over the wall I was stuck against. Thank for your time and knowledge. I'll mark as accepted and I'm sure I'll be back if I get stuck again.

Comment: No worries. Take some time to read [```requests```](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) documentation. There is also this nice tutorial on Real Python: [Python’s Requests Library (Guide)](https://realpython.com/python-requests/).

Comment: Somehow the file upload doesn't look correct to me.
Pls check https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#advanced

I'd expect more something like
`requests.post(entry_point, headers=headers, data=data, files=files)`

where files is something like `files={ "files": ("47.htz" ,open('foo.htz', 'rb') }`
and remove the `files` key from tha `data` field

Comment: @gelonida, if possible, create another question and post your code so we can follow up there and you will get more people looking into the issue.

Comment: you mean another answer???

I just think, the answer might not be completely correct 
I have the impression that the answer would post a `files` field with the value "@47.htz" whereas curl takes the contents of the file 47.htz and posts it as a file field.

Posting file fields with requests is mentioned in the url I posted in above comment. and should look roughly like a added in my comment.

I thought it's better to comment on your answer, so that it can be corrected if my assumptions are right.

Though in prev comment `foo.htz` should be `47.htz`

Comment: I mean another question since it is a new issue. The answer is based on what was posted on the OP. There is no mention about uploading a file or something and, as far as I can see, the request is just updating metadata about of an existing item. But I may be wrong since I have no idea about that API. My answer was about Python and requests exclusively. :-)

Comment: This code is wrong. The curl command sends the data in [`multipart/form-data` format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#multipartform-data), but the generated requests code, even though it sets the `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data`, actually sends the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` because you used the `data=` parameter instead of [`files=`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you try pasting your curl command into [curlconverter.com](https://curlconverter.com) again, it now generates correct requests code:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    # requests won't add a boundary if this header is set when you pass files=
    # 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}

files = {
    'files': open('47.htz', 'rb'),
    'name': (None, '47'),
    'oldMediaId': (None, '47'),
    'updateInLayouts': (None, '1'),
    'deleteOldRevisions': (None, '1'),
}

response = requests.post('http://129.12.19.62/api/library', headers=headers, files=files)
```